# Regex for dashed class names

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a strings that looks like this:

"wes-1 className Another"
"wes-2-bos className Another"
"wes-3 className Another"
"wes-5-bos className Another"

I need to return the ones that are wes-* and delete everything else.

Regex makes my head spin, any help?

using js. This is what I have so far..

```
str.match(/\b^wes/);
```

Comment: Good resource to learn about regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str.match(/wes-[\w-]*/)
```

matches wes- and any number of word or - characters after it.

Comment: the regex goes like this: match the litteral `wes-` followed by 0 or more (that's what the wildcard * does) characters in a particular character class.  the character class is defined as any of the characters between the `[]`.  so in this case, we have `\w`s and `-`s.  lastly, \w is a word character.  it excludes character returns, spaces and a few symbols.  so in english: wes- followed by 0 or more word characters or dashes.